# Teams token not getting generated on Mobile app but works fine on Web and Desktop

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

My custom app is in Angular and everything was working fine till a few weeks back. I was able to log in and generate tokens on both Web and Mobile app versions for the custom app but surprisingly now, it has stopped working now. I cannot see where the issue is now. I have tested on Android ( Version 11 )

"@microsoft/teams-js": "1.10.0"

Here is my code snippet.

```js
import * as microsoftTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js';

microsoftTeams.initialize(() => {
      this.microsoftAppAuth();
 });

microsoftAppAuth() {
    microsoftTeams.registerOnThemeChangeHandler((theme) => {
      setTheme(theme);
    });

    function setTheme(theme) {
      if (theme) {
        document.body.className =
          'theme-' + (theme === 'default' ? 'light' : theme);
        localStorage.setItem('theme', document.body.className);
      }
    }

    const authTokenRequest = {
      successCallback: (result) => {
        this.authService.setToken(result);
        microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess(); // important in case of "showLoadingIndicator": true in manifest file
        localStorage.setItem('msteam', '1');
      },

      failureCallback: (error) => {
        console.log('Inside Teams Login Failure: ' + error);
      },
    };
    microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => {
       if (context) {
        if (context.theme) {
          setTheme(context.theme);
        }
        if (context.locale !== undefined && context.locale !== '') {
          this.translateService.use(context.locale.match(/es|es-ES/) ? 'es' : 'en');
        }
      }
      microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken(authTokenRequest);
    });
  }
```

Like I mentioned in the title, the above code works fine in the Teams web version the only issue I am facing is on Mobile App.

Comment: Hello, 
I tried with the code you share and didn't faced any issue on Android mobile. Can you please check once after re-login from your mobile?

Comment: Hey, Is this issue resolved?

Comment: yes this issue resolved